# How to understand the following C# linq code of implementing the algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n

Tags: c#, .net, linq, recursion, combinatorics

Anyone can elaborate some details on this code or even give a non-Linq version of this algorithm:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>
    (this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
   return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] }
                 : elements.SelectMany(
                       (e, i) =>
                         elements
                         .Skip(i + 1)
                         .Combinations(k - 1)
                         .Select(c => (new[] {e}).Concat(c)));
}
```

Comment: That would depend on how `Combinations` is defined, which you haven't shown. It isn't a standard LINQ method

Comment: @Asad It's a recursive method.

Comment: @GertArnold Oh, duh.

Comment: This would be awful on performance if `elements` was deferred!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to understand this code is to read the amazing serial post from Eric Lippert:

- [Producing combinations, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/)
- [Producing combinations, part two](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/16/producing-combinations-part-two/)
- [Producing combinations, part three](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/20/producing-combinations-part-three/)
- [Producing combinations, part four](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/23/producing-combinations-part-four/)
- [Producing combinations, part five](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/27/producing-combinations-part-five/)

Basically, if we have a `IEnumerable` of 5 items, and want to get all combinations size of 3, we need to produce something like this:

```
{
                      // 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
    {50, 60, 70},     // T   T   T   F   F
    {50, 60, 80},     // T   T   F   T   F
    {50, 60, 90},     // T   T   F   F   T
    {50, 70, 80},     // T   F   T   T   F
    {50, 70, 90},     // T   F   T   F   T
    {50, 80, 90},     // T   F   F   T   T
    {60, 70, 80},     // F   T   T   T   F
    {60, 70, 90},     // F   T   T   F   T
    {60, 80, 90},     // F   T   F   T   T
    {70, 80, 90}      // F   F   T   T   T
}
```

Eric's recursive implementation:

```
// Takes integers n and k, both non-negative.
// Produces all sets of exactly k elements consisting only of 
// integers from 0 through n - 1.
private static IEnumerable<TinySet> Combinations(int n, int k)
{
  // Base case: if k is zero then there can be only one set
  // regardless of the value of n: the empty set is the only set
  // with zero elements.
  if (k == 0)
  { 
    yield return TinySet.Empty;
    yield break;
  }

  // Base case: if n < k then there can be no set of exactly
  // k elements containing values from 0 to n - 1, because sets
  // do not contain repeated elements.

  if (n < k)
    yield break;

  // A set containing k elements where each is an integer from
  // 0 to n - 2 is also a set of k elements where each is an
  // integer from 0 to n - 1, so yield all of those.

  foreach(var r in Combinations(n-1, k))
    yield return r;

  // If we add n - 1 to all the sets of k - 1 elements where each
  // is an integer from 0 to n - 2, then we get a set of k elements
  // where each is an integer from 0 to n - 1.

  foreach(var r in Combinations(n-1, k-1))
    yield return r.Add(n-1);
}
```

In your case, the code is working like this:

```
   return k == 0
     // if we are done, return empty array
     ? new[] {new T[0]}
     // for each element and each number from 0 to enumerable size
     : elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
                            elements
     //skip first i elements, as we already produced combination with them
                            .Skip(i + 1)
     //get all the combinations with size k - 1
                            .Combinations(k - 1)
     //add current element to all produced combinations
                            .Select(c => (new[] {e}).Concat(c)));
```

This code in non-recursive form will be very huge and unreadable, try to understand the recursion:

Say, we have a 5 elements `IEnumerable`: `{ 16, 13, 2, 4, 100 }`, and we need to all the combinations from it with size of 2 (total numbers of resulting sets is equal to [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) from 5 to 2 `= 5! / (2! * 3!) = 10`)

Your code will be producing:

1. For the `16` we need all the combinations of size `1`, starting from second position:
2. For the element `13` we need all the combinations of size `0` starting from the third position
3. First result: `{ 16, 13 }`
4. Skip the `13`, For the element `2` we need all the combinations of size `0` starting from the fourth position
5. Second result: `{ 16, 2 }`
6. Skip the `13, 2`, For the element `4` we need all the combinations of size `0` starting from the fifth position
7. Third result: `{ 16, 4 }`
8. Skip the `13, 2, 4`, For the element `100` we need all the combinations of size `0` starting from the sixth position
9. Fourth result: `{ 16, 100 }`
10. ... repeat all the above from `13`, `2`, `4`:
    `{ 13, 2 }`, `{ 13, 4 }`, `{ 13, 100 }`, `{ 2, 4 }`, `{ 2, 100 }`, `{ 4, 100 }`

And we got all the 10 combinations we need. The overload the code author is using is this: [`Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, IEnumerable<TResult>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549142.aspx):

> selector
>   Type: `System.Func<TSource, Int32, IEnumerable<TResult>>`
>   A transform function to apply to each source element;
>   the second parameter of the function represents **the index of the source element.**

Comment: That is a very good answer. I was wondering, where does the 'i' come into this? 'e' I understand is the element in the collection, does that mean that 'i' is the index of 'e' or is that just an arbitrary index? I know this isn't part of the question and I have never really used two parameters in a lambda before.

Comment: The second argument for the select lambda is the index of the current element.

Comment: @Keithin8a added the link to the MSDN. Yes, it is an index of currently observing element

Comment: @VMAtm, thanks for the dedicated introduction and explanations!

Answer (score 0):

My none linq version, should be correct!

Test results:

Linq style:

```
123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345
```

My way:

```
123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345
```

My Code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the full combinations of k elements from a given list.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<List<T>> MyCombinations<T>(this List<T> elements, int k)
    {
        int n = elements.Count;
        //Given the same sequence, what if we wish to choose none of them? There does exist a subsequence which has zero elements, so we should produce it; the answer would be { { } }
        if (k == 0)
        {
            return new List<List<T>> {new List<T> {}};
        }
        if (k == n)
        {
            return new List<List<T>> {elements};
        }
        // What if we have a sequence of five items and we wish to choose six of them? There is no way to do that; there is no six-element subsequence. So the answer should be { }, the empty sequence of sequences
        if (k > n)
        {
            return new List<List<T>> {};
        }
        var result = new List<List<T>> {};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            T cur = elements[i];
            var rest = elements.Skip(i + 1).ToList();//take out current elment to fetch combinations of the rest set
            var combinationsOfRest = MyCombinations<T>(rest, k - 1);
            var currentList = new List<T> {cur};
            foreach (List<T> combination in combinationsOfRest)
            {
                result.Add(currentList.Concat(combination).ToList());
                //combination.Add(cur);
                //result.Add(combination);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```